# Enable to show Golf cart Path along with driving path on mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox, openstreetmap, driving-directions

I am using mapbox version 0.21.0 [(navigation mapbox)](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android) in my application , we need to show driving path along with Golf cart path.But map box is providing only driving direction not golf cart. So is there anyway to find out golf cart path.[link](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/190129935#map=17/28.90567/-81.98081)

Thanks for help
[image: golf cart sample image]

Comment: If the library you're using does not provide a pre-tracked path on the roads you want to take, then it won't be possible to show it in your app. Or, you have to trace them yourself, by encoding several geographic points and linking them

Comment: crossposts: https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/6157 and https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1165 and https://github.com/westnordost/StreetComplete/issues/1230 and https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/issues/347 and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/1403.

Comment: As mentioned in answer to the github spam: "in places where you can ask for help (stackoverflow or similar) you should ask it in a way that shows a research effort". At least link to documentation that declares that "providing only driving direction not golf cart" and explain what is "golf cart path".

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny sample image & also check golf cart route on map

Comment: https://villagesgps.com/

Comment: On which roads/paths are you allowed to drive with a golf cart? In the end this is just boils down to a specific routing profile. For example by allowing routing on regular roads (for cars) and also on cycleways. Which would essentially be a bicycle router.

Comment: @scai we are using bicycle route for Golf Cart, but its give 70 % right path. if the path will be wrong then you pay penalty for this. you can also check Flordia city law for the Golf cart.

Comment: So use one of the bicycle routers and inspect the wrong parts. Try to understand why they are wrong and if either OSM data needs improvement or the bicycle routing profile.

Answer (score 0):

As OpenStreetMap project maps the real world it should not be expected to contain map data from computer games.

So, it is not a suitable source of golf cart paths in a world in specific games.